# Spring boot addFlashAttribute not displaying message in HTML

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, redirect, thymeleaf

I've been searching here and online how to use addFlashAttribute in the best way and it's not working for me no matter what I do. I have a Student model which I'm trying to update and flash message of success or fail. The database and all the queries do work and I get redirected to the showStudentDetail page, it's just the message that doesn't show. Here is the code:

StudentService:

```
public String updateStudent(Student student) {
    if(studentDAO.update(student))
        return "update student was successful!";
    return "error: failed to update student, please try again";
}

public Student getStudentInfo(String username) {
    Student student = studentDAO.get(username);
    return student;
}
```

StudentController:

```
@PostMapping("/updateStudent")
public String updateStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    String res = studentService.updateStudent(student);
    redirectAttrs.addAttribute("username", student.getUsername()).addFlashAttribute("message", res);
    return "redirect:/students/{username}/details";
}

@GetMapping("/students/{username}/details")
public String showDetailPage(@PathVariable String username, Model model) {
    Student student = studentService.getStudentInfo(username);
    model.addAttribute("student", student);
    return "student_detail";
}
```

student_detail (div not showing)

```
<div>
    <div th:if="${param.username}" class="alert alert-info" role="alert" th:text="${param.message}"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by changing to message instead of param.message.
I really don't know why now it's working but that's the solution to my problem.

only change the html to this:

```
<div th:if="${message}" class="alert alert-info" role="alert" th:text="${message}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the model in the controller is student, but in the view you are using "param" name. Change "param" to "student".

Comment: when I changed it to student it gave me an error when tryin to load the page with "property or field message cannot be found on object"

Comment: Do you have public getters in the Entity?

Comment: in student entity I have getter and setter

Comment: It should work fine, I don't know what's the problem. Maybe try to seperate th:if and th:text, with div and span elements, or maybe try instead of div with span element. I had some problems with thymeleaf too. Now I checked, I always use span elements. Documentation says it should work fine with div too, but for me using span was the solution. Also try the text without if, maybe the if statement is wrong something.

     <div>
     <div th:if="${student.username}" class="alert alert-info" role="alert"</div>
    <span th:text="${student.message}"> </span>
    </div>